# using -exec command on mac os x

Tags: bash

Does any know why the `-exec` does not work on mac os x lion terminal?

It works on linux and other variants but not on mac os x

```
find / -iname "*.mp3" -exec mv {} /mnt/mp3 \;
```

Comment: It works fine for me, although /mnt/mp3 isn't a location you're likely to find on OS X; if "mp3" is a mounted volume, generally it'll be mounted at /Volumes/mp3.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to move the mp3's to a place which exists on OSX already?

Comment: Patrix, I know that but my point is that the command some odd reason doesn't work on my mac os x lion. The issue is not where the destination is. I'll see if I can post the error message..

Comment: I concur with @GordonDavisson – that command works just fine as is. Are you certain that you have write rights to `/mnt/mp3`?

Comment: Perhaps you omitted the space ahead of `\;` That yields the error: `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`.